How to set a custom heading number in .docx file using python-docx?
Using this code the script automatically set the heading number:
paragraph.insert_paragraph_before(style='Heading 2', text='heading2')，

How can I set a custom heading number through my script?

please can you share screenshot what is the current output and highlight where you want to change in doc.
